# Sourcing Alias Prevents Less Buffer From Displaying

Tags: zsh, alias

I'm writing a bash script that needs to both be able to `cd` in the current shell and use `less` to display longform text. To be able to `cd`, I understand that I need to `source` the script when I call it, which I've done via an alias in my ZSH config. However, when I do this, `less` breaks: instead of `echo -e "$result" | less` displaying its usual scrolling buffer, the long text gets dumped into the shell.

For context, this is a bash script acting as a wrapper for a Node.js script so as to be able to have native access to bash commands (like `cd`, `open`, etc.). The alias in my zshrc is as follows (with the path truncated): `alias bk='source ~/.../bookmark/bookmark.sh'`.

Is there any way to satisfy both the need to `cd` and the need to use `less`?

Comment: Did you put the option `-F` ? Note that you can put `less` options in a `$LESS` env var. Check out `man less`.

Comment: Do you mean using `-F` as a flag for `source`, or a flag for `less`? I just tried the latter; no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! This turned out to be an issue in my script's logic. I was using `condition=$(echo $result | cut -c 1-3)`, but in reality need the first three characters (not columns) of `$result`, which I then did by using `$result | head -c 3`. What's interesting about this is that fetching the first three columns from `$result` when determined by running `./bookmark.sh` works as an equivalent to fetching the first three characters, but running the alias yields the issue here.

Comment: Please accept your own answer, so this question doesn't stay open.

Comment: My apologies, meant to do this earlier. Thank you for the bump.